# How to mock EKEventStore

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, mocking

I have a simple function for requesting access for adding events in the Calendar.

```
typealias BoolCallback = (Bool) -> ()

class SimpleCalendar {

    let store: EKEventStore

    init(store: EKEventStore = EKEventStore()) {
        self.store = store
    }

    /// Request access to EventKit API for Calendar intergration
    ///
    /// - Parameter callback: returns if access was recived or denied
    func requestAccess(callback: @escaping BoolCallback) {

        let status = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event)

        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            callback(true)
            //        case .notDetermined: //should ask for access
        //        case .denied, .restricted: //should open a ask permission view
        default:
            store.requestAccess(to: .event) { accessGranted, _ in

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    callback(accessGranted)
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Is there a way to mock `EKEventStore` for getting the status?

I also have a simple function that checks if a calendar exists.

```
func doesCalendarExist(name: String) -> Bool {
    let calendars = store.calendars(for: .event)

    if calendars.contains(where: { $0.title == name }) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Is there a way to mock the store objects for getting `store.calendars`

Thanks

---

I switched

```
let status = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event)
```

to

```
let status = type(of: store).authorizationStatus(for: .event)
```

Comment: please check new update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use DI here. Instead of put responsibility of creating store var inside of **SimpleCalendar** you can create constructor for it with parameter **store: EKEventStore** and pass it there:

```
init(store: EKEventStore = EKEventStore()) {/*code*/}
```

This way, you can pass your own mock object.

What is the issue with overriding class method? I can't check it right now, but suppose it's possible.

Any way, other option is for mocking you can create protocol with all the methods you're using - **EventStoreProtocol**. These methods must be in **EKEventStore** I think, so you can easily adopt it using extension:

```
extension EKEventStore: EventStoreProtocol {}
```

Then instead of passing **EKEventStore** to constructor, pass there **EventStoreProtocol**.

Your mock object will be not subclass, but just class confirming to that protocol, implementing all required methods

For class method, instead of **EKEventStore.authorizationStatus** use **type(of: store).authorizationStatus**

The only thing I can think of regarding your problem is the next:

```
extension EKEventStore {
   func eventAuthorizationStatus() -> EKAuthorizationStatus {
      return EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event)
   }
}
```

Then override this method in subclass. Because **EKEventStore** is **NSObject**, it should work (but I'm not sure). This way instead of using **type(of: store).authorizationStatus** you can call this method.

But the question - do you really need this? Can't you just left it as is? If no, check this approach and tell me, if it works

Comment: Thanks, this works for 'doesCalendarExist' function but do you know how can i mock a class method 'EKEventStore.authorizationStatus'

Comment: Thanks again, i will explain the problem with class methods.
as you can see i am calling 'EKEventStore.authorizationStatus' in my code this is a class method so i cant use DI

Comment: @ilan, I think you can - as your instance will be another class, you have to access class from the instance and call its method. so, instead of EKEventStore.authorizationStatus put type(of: store).authorizationStatus

Comment: i didnt understand the code part, can you add it to your answer?

Comment: may be you can write it with more description? :)

Comment: I get 'EKEventStore!' has no member 'authorizationStatus'

Comment: show me all related code please. just add it to your question

Comment: show the declaration of store, constructor and your extension, if you used second approach

Comment: this is everything. i used the first approach